# Why do we write $a^n$ instead of $^n\!a$ for exponentiation?

Tags: notation, math-history

For subtraction I can understand why $2-3 = 2+(-3)$ since we read from left to right, but I don't see why this need apply to exponentiation. What benefit is there to writing the base before the exponent? With addition and multiplication order doesn't matter since $a+b=b+a$, so why was $a^n$ chosen, and who popularised this notation?

A similar question, with the focus on the historical reasons, has also been asked on [History of Science and Math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/705/who-invented-the-way-we-write-exponentiation).

Comment: @user201168 I'm aware that $^n\!a$ is used for tetration, but that's not my question.

Comment: Seems like an arbitrary choice. What is the reasoning behind seeing the exponent before the base (or vice versa)?

Comment: Convention. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @par $3\times 2$ is read as "Three two's added". $3^2$ can be read as "two three's multiplied".

Comment: You should browse Cajori's *History of Mathematical Notations*.

Comment: @fvel: What about three multiplied by itself twice?

Comment: "with multiplication order doesn't matter", is not always true.  It depends on what number system you are in.  Matrices and quaternions for example do not usually commute.

Comment: From a purely typographical point of view alone the common notation seems a lot more natural to me.

Comment: @par You can multiply three by itself a hundred times, you will still get nine every time.

Comment: Is it ust as useful to ask why not?

Comment: @par I didn't exclude the other, but treating exponentiation with the symbol $^$ you often need to apply this is as right-assosiative. $a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)}$ while $a-b-c = (a-b)-c$ and $a \div b \div c = (a\div b) \div c$, which is left-assosiative. So it breaks a pattern.

Comment: Also multiplication is $a+a = 2a$ so why wouldn't $a\times a = ^2\!a$

Comment: @bof because people with sloppy hand-writing would not know anymore if it was the former or the latter. :-)

Comment: Seems to me that it’s just history, and little else. The pain caused, now at this late date, by changing the notation would be far greater than the minor annoyance that we all suffer by working with a notation that is suboptimal.

Comment: @Lubin I'm not asking for a change, although imagine all the nice things we could have if we could change bad notation... Although I might use the other one for personal use, as I like trying out different notations.

Comment: In set theory, $^\omega2$ and $2^\omega$ are used with two different meanings; the former is the set of all functions from $\omega$ to $2$, the latter is the number of such functions and is the product of a countable infinity of $2$s. Would you like to interchange those two notations?

Comment: This is a guess. But one should recall that in the old times people thought more in geometric terms, with $a^2$, $a^3$ being measures of the square and cube of the respective dimensions. And this *meaning* of the quantity was implitly there even in more abstract considerations. In that sense, *originally* the exponent signaled/corresponded to specifying units. So one has $90^2$ like one has $90$ miles or meters or seconds and not miles $90$, seconds $30$ and so on.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche The reason I wanted to ask was to know if there were some advantages of the notation, although given that the advantages may be of historical reasons and not practical reasons I might ask it over there as well.

Answer (score 8):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Background_and_terminology) says "The modern notation for exponentiation was introduced by René Descartes in his Géométrie of 1637", and has a link to [a page from Descartes](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b86069594/f383.image).

Comment: This answer just answers a part of the question. I'll admit the question is poorly phrased, but I was hoping to get the answer to "What benefit is there to writing the base before the exponent?", and this doesn't. Nor does it say "why was $a^n$ chosen". Although both have been addressed and partly answered in the comment section of the question.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to say that it's also because of the way we read.

$2^3$ is "two to the cube" or "two to the third" whereas $^23$ would be "to two, the three?".

Of course, this could be very bad reason since you can argue that the operation $3^2$ existed before we decided to read it...

(I wanted to write this as a comment better than a proper answer, but I can't write comments yet I'm afraid)

Comment: a squared three? Of course the way we read these things were made up after the notation, so that's not a good argument.

Comment: @fvel this is actually debatable. Earlier math was written in a more verbal way; and even now often the ideas and talking about them comes before notations are decided on.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I wanted to write it as a comment. It didn't feel like an actual answer, but I felt it was worth pointing this out.

Comment: @quid Good point, although that raises the question, why would you say "two to the third" instead of "a cubed two"...

Comment: "The cube of two" and "the third power of two" sound only slightly stilted to me.  We very often talk about "powers of two", so it's not like it's too alien.

Comment: @fvel: actually algebraic notation came long after people first talked and wrote about mathematics.

Comment: It sounds more "Ye Olde Exponentiation" to say it like "To two, the three. Aha, Romeo!"